# Apply gradient descent only if TensorFlow model improves on training and validation data

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I want to customize the `fit` function of the model in order to apply the gradient descent on the weights only if the model improved its predictions on the validation data. The reason for this is that I want to prevent overfitting.

According to this [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit) it should be possible to customize the `fit` function of the model. However, the following code runs into errors:

```
class CustomModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        x, y = data

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(x, training=True)
            loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred, regularization_losses=self.losses)

        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

        ### check and apply gradient
        Y_pred_val = self.predict(X_val)                 # this does not work
        acc_val = calculate_accuracy(Y_val, Y_pred_val)

        if acc_val > last_acc_val:
            self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))
        ###

        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)

        return_obj = {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
        return_obj["acc_val"] = acc_val
        return return_obj
```

How could it be possible to evaluate the model inside the `fit` function?

Comment: wouldn't this instead increase overfitting: essentially fitting on both train and validation data ?

Comment: @dm2 well, the gradient descent is based on a random batch of the train data and it would be applied only if that would be also good for the validation data. At least overfitting between train and validation data would not be possible. Nevertheless, overfitting still can occur if comparing to an unseen test dataset.

Comment: Are you planning to provide feedback to answers to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to subclass `fit()` for this. You can just make a custom training loop. Look how I did that:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
from tensorflow.keras import Model
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Concatenate
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l1, l2, l1_l2
from collections import deque

dataset, info = tfds.load('mnist',
                          with_info=True,
                          split='train',
                          as_supervised=False)

TAKE = 1_000

data = dataset.map(lambda x: (tf.cast(x['image'],
                       tf.float32), x['label'])).shuffle(TAKE).take(TAKE)

len_train = int(8e-1*TAKE)

train = data.take(len_train).batch(8)
test = data.skip(len_train).take(info.splits['train'].num_examples - len_train).batch(8)


class CNN(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = Dense(32, activation=tf.nn.relu,
                            kernel_regularizer=l1(1e-2),
                            input_shape=info.features['image'].shape)
        self.layer2 = Conv2D(filters=16,
                             kernel_size=(3, 3),
                             strides=(1, 1),
                             activation='relu',
                             input_shape=info.features['image'].shape)
        self.layer3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))
        self.layer4 = Conv2D(filters=32,
                             kernel_size=(3, 3),
                             strides=(1, 1),
                             activation=tf.nn.elu,
                             kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal)
        self.layer5 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))
        self.layer6 = Flatten()
        self.layer7 = Dense(units=64,
                            activation=tf.nn.relu,
                            kernel_regularizer=l2(1e-2))
        self.layer8 = Dense(units=64,
                            activation=tf.nn.relu,
                            kernel_regularizer=l1_l2(l1=1e-2, l2=1e-2))
        self.layer9 = Concatenate()
        self.layer10 = Dense(units=info.features['label'].num_classes)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, **kwargs):
        b = self.layer1(inputs)
        a = self.layer2(inputs)
        a = self.layer3(a)
        a = self.layer4(a)
        a = self.layer5(a)
        a = self.layer6(a)
        a = self.layer8(a)
        b = self.layer7(b)
        b = self.layer6(b)
        x = self.layer9([a, b])
        x = self.layer10(x)
        return x


cnn = CNN()

loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
test_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()

train_acc = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()
test_acc = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam()

template = 'Epoch {:3} Train Loss {:7.4f} Test Loss {:7.4f} ' \
           'Train Acc {:6.2%} Test Acc {:6.2%} '

epochs = 5
early_stop = epochs//50

loss_hist = deque()
acc_hist = deque(maxlen=1)
acc_hist.append(0)

for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
    train_loss.reset_states()
    test_loss.reset_states()
    train_acc.reset_states()
    test_acc.reset_states()

    for images, labels in train:
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            logits = cnn(images, training=True)
            loss = loss_object(labels, logits)
            train_loss(loss)
            train_acc(labels, logits)

            current_acc = tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()(labels, logits)

            if tf.greater(current_acc, acc_hist[-1]):
                print('IMPROVEMENT.')
                gradients = tape.gradient(loss, cnn.trainable_variables)
                optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, cnn.trainable_variables))
                acc_hist.append(current_acc)

    for images, labels in test:
        logits = cnn(images, training=False)
        loss = loss_object(labels, logits)
        test_loss(loss)
        test_acc(labels, logits)

    print(template.format(epoch,
                          train_loss.result(),
                          test_loss.result(),
                          train_acc.result(),
                          test_acc.result()))

    if len(loss_hist) > early_stop and loss_hist.popleft() < min(loss_hist):
        print('Early stopping. No validation loss decrease in %i epochs.' % early_stop)
        break
```

Output:

```
IMPROVEMENT.
IMPROVEMENT.
IMPROVEMENT.
IMPROVEMENT.
Epoch   1 Train Loss 21.1698 Test Loss 21.3391 Train Acc 37.13% Test Acc 38.50% 
IMPROVEMENT.
IMPROVEMENT.
IMPROVEMENT.
Epoch   2 Train Loss 13.8314 Test Loss 12.2496 Train Acc 50.88% Test Acc 52.50% 
Epoch   3 Train Loss 13.7594 Test Loss 12.5884 Train Acc 51.75% Test Acc 53.00% 
Epoch   4 Train Loss 13.1418 Test Loss 13.2374 Train Acc 52.75% Test Acc 51.50% 
Epoch   5 Train Loss 13.6471 Test Loss 13.3157 Train Acc 49.63% Test Acc 51.50%
```

Here's the part that did the job. It's a `deque` and it skips the application of gradients if the last element of the `deque` is smaller.

```
    for images, labels in train:
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            logits = cnn(images, training=True)
            loss = loss_object(labels, logits)
            train_loss(loss)
            train_acc(labels, logits)

            current_acc = tf.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()(labels, logits)

            if tf.greater(current_acc, acc_hist[-1]):
                print('IMPROVEMENT.')
                gradients = tape.gradient(loss, cnn.trainable_variables)
                optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, cnn.trainable_variables))
                acc_hist.append(current_acc)
```

Comment: It looks promising, but I am facing one problem: The accuracy is calculated on the current model and then if it improved the model is updated. But I would rather update the model only if the accuracy would increase. How could I achieve this?

Comment: That's exactly what the `if` statement does

Answer (score 0):

Rather than create a `custom fit` I think it would be easier to use the `callback ModelCheckpoint`. 
What you are trying to do is get the model that has the lowest validation error. Set it up to monitor validation loss. That way it will save the best model even if the network starts to over fit. 
Documentation is [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint)

If you do not get a model with a satisfactory validation accuracy then you will have to take other measures. 
First look at your *training accuracy*.
My experience is that you should achieve at *least 95%*.
If the training accuracy is good but the validation accuracy is poor and degrades as you run more epochs that is a sign of over fitting.
You did not show the model but if you are doing classification you will probably have dense layers with the final layer using `softmax activation`.
Start out with model with only one dense layer and see if it trains well.

If not you may have to add additional dense hidden layers. If you do include a drop out layer to help prevent over fitting. You might also consider using *regularizers*. Documentation is
[here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/regularizers/Regularizer). 
I also find you can get improved performance if you dynamically adjust the learning rate. The callback `ReduceLROnPlateau` enables that capability.
Set it up to monitor validation loss and to reduce the learning rate by a factor if the loss fails to decrease. Documentation is [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ReduceLROnPlateau)